# Scrollview blocking parentview

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, touch, subview

I have scrollview bottom of the screen. when i click the button it load the scrollview. But the scrollview is occupies full parentview. I can't control bottom the view for some rectMake. If i use scrollview i can't handle some other button actions and click event for other subviews.

code:

```
scrollview=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,self.view.frame.size.height)]; 

  scrollview.scrollEnabled=YES;
for (int i = 0; i<[self.array count]; i++ ) {
            NSLog(@"index %d",i);



            imgView1=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20+(i*74), 500, 72, 72)];


            [imgView1 setTag:i+1];

            [imgView1 addTarget:self action:@selector(Clicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

            [imgView1 setImage:((Mysof *)[self.array objectAtIndex:i]).photo forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            [scrollview addSubview:imgView1];


    }

         [scrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(CGRectGetMaxX(imgView1.frame),self.view.frame.size.height)];

        [self.view addSubview:scrollview];
```

Log:

```
scroll is <UIScrollView: 0x1f03d550; frame = (0 0; 320 568); clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1f037090>; layer = <CALayer: 0x1f036670>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
```

Comment: I recommend you to print frame of a scrollview before & after setting contentsize. And let me know the output. Probably I can help you over this

Comment: log the frame for your scrollview

Comment: check the edited question with log

Comment: do you want the answer. Or you got your solution with the accepted answer?

Comment: It's working. But when i scroll the scrollview on vertical, the scrollview is gone. I want only horizontal scroll

Comment: ok.so what you have set for contentsize?

Comment: [scrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(CGRectGetMaxX(imgView1.frame),self.view.frame.size.height)];

Comment: yes that you have already written in your question. But what is the log for contentsize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing like this:

```
scrollview=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,self.view.frame.size.height)];
```

instead Try this:

```
int y = self.view.frame.origin.y+ self.view.frame.size.height-200;
scrollview=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,y,320,200)];
```

Here, Scrollview will be displayed at bottom of the view and it will be of 320X200 size. you can change the height as per your requirements. when you change Height then also change value at self.view.frame.origin.y+ self.view.frame.size.height-changedHeight.

and make Imageview Frame Like this:

```
imgView1=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20+(i*74), 0, 72, 72)];
```

Content size should be smaller then scrollview height for only horizontal scroll.
Here, Width should be total of your all imageview's width+ given space. so i would say that try using Width variable like this in your for loop and use that Width to content size so it would set as per total width of images.

```
    int Width = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<[self.array count]; i++ ) {

      Width = Width + 20+(i*74);
    }

  [scrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(Width,imgView1.frame.size.height+20)];
```

Hope it Helps!!

Comment: it looks like you are getting wrong values for Y position in Frame. so i would suggest that take equation self.view.frame.origin.y+ self.view.frame.size.height-200 in any int value and then assign to cgrect() and check what value its giving.

Comment: when i scroll the scrollview on vertical, the scrollview is gone to top. I want only horizontal scroll

Answer (score 0):

Set the scrollView's height as a origin of the bottom button,

```
scrollview=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,400)];
```

Here i assume that your button/ bottom view's y position as 400. Instead you can change as your need